# MSBuild compiling ASP.NET MVC4 application - designed using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am desperately looking out for a solution to my problem, my problem is with MSBuild continuous integration setup for my project which is designed using Visual Studio 2015.

Well I have not used all the new flavors out from VS 2015. Because my deployment server is configured with very old server OS i.e. Windows server 2003.

Hence the reason within VS 2015 I have designed my project to use .net framework 4.0 with ASP.NET MVC version 4 only. Which is only the version supported in Windows server 2003.

So, until the design time my application is compiling perfectly without throwing any reference error's.

When I am done writing MSBuild compilation setup and ran build using MSBuild.exe it is throwing below errors:

1. CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Workspaces\myProject\myProject.Web\myProject.Web.csproj
2. CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Workspaces\myProject\myProject.Web\myProject.Web.csproj
3. CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Workspaces\myProject\myProject.Web\myProject.Web.csproj
4. CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Workspaces\myProject\myProject.Web\myProject.Web.csproj
5. CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Workspaces\myProject\myProject.Web\myProject.Web.csproj

Like these there are total 70 errors found while doing compilation using MSBuild command.

Please help me out how this issue can be fixed!

Thanks in advance

Vijay

Comment: Do you mean you could success building it through Visual Studio 2015? What's the version of MSBuild tool?

Comment: no I pointed MSBuild toold to correct version by providing physical path as "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild". But as I mentioned in above the issue which is causing for dll were added for old version of MVC i.e. MVC V4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC 4 project is removed in VS 2015, but the tooling support for MVC 4 project is available in VS 2015 update 1 RC. More information, you can refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591926.aspx) article.

So, you can create a MVC 4 project with .net framework 4.0 in VS 2013 and open it in VS 2015 update 1 RC or higher. It will throw many errors as yours if you change the .net framework to .net framework 4.0 of higher version of MVC project, for example, create MVC 4 project with .net framework 4.5 in VS 2015.
I shared a MVC 4 project with default template [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AresBGZVYryjhRsuOZl0bWTj7fbN) (created in VS 2013), that you could use in VS 2015.

Comment: Starain, I have already followed the steps provided, my concern is not about how to run MVC 4 app in VS 2015. 

My concern is all about how I can run my CI build (using Bamboo or Jenkins) with these set of configurations, I also pasted couple of error from Bamboo error logs.

Comment: Could you build it through MSBuild tool? What's the problem of Bamboo or Jenkins? I don't find Bamboo error logs just MSBuild tool.

Comment: Yes I build it through MSBuild locally and it is throwing me the same error(s). I am still wonder why it is misbehaving like this, where as building the same application in VS is giving no errors. :(

Comment: @Vijay Using MSBuild tool that in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin to build your project. (x86 bit machine: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\...)